# FBLoginView works on iPhone Simulator, but not on actual device

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, swift, facebook-login

I have created an app that allows a user to login using facebook via the FacebookSDK. I can successfully login while running the app on the iPhone Simulator as an iPhone 5 or 5S (i haven't tried any other devices). But, when I run the app on my iPhone 5 the FBLoginView doesn't work. More specifically, when I tap the view (the 'Log In' button) the color changes to a slightly darker blue to acknowledge that the touch was received, but nothing else happens. Normally, a browser would open and request my Facebook credentials, but that does not happen.

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

FYI, I am using XCode 6 Beta 5.

#### Update:

I took John's advice in the comments below and uninstalled the Facebook app and I also deleted the OS Facebook account. This worked for me. My app correctly received the callback from Safari. I re-installed the Facebook and tried it again and my app still worked (receiving the callback from the Facebook app).*But, when I logged back into the OS Facebook account my app no longer received the callback.*

I am currently using the supplied FBLoginView. I think from this point I will implement a custom login view for Facebook so that I can apply breakpoints on each of the functions.

I am wondering at this point if this isn't an issue with the Beta version of iOS 8. I am not entirely convinced that it is because I have been unable to find mention of other developers having this same issue. Just a thought

Comment: Do you have the actual Facebook app on your device?

Comment: I do have to the latest Facebook app on my device.

Comment: I had to uninstall it / sign out for login to work in my apps.

Comment: oh dude, you shouldn't be posting functionality questions like this based off of Xcode betas..... what you get may not be what you expect....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues cleared themselves up. They appear to have been related to the beta release of Xcode or the Swift language.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Facebook SDK, login events are handled differently depending on the environment. You may want to check all callbacks as the Facebook SDK can use the settings fb credentials, pages app, Facebook app, or web view to log in...

Comment: Would it be an issue with a callback? When running the app on the device it never asks me to login, so I wouldn't think it would ever get to the point of calling-back.

Comment: it could be calling back to the delegate or callback method and you might not be checking for every possible state that can be returned from the callback. All because it doesn't ask you to log in doesn't mean something isn't happening. Breakpoint all the callback methods from the Facebook authentication request and check.

Comment: Also ensure you are checking for errors. Remember that certain accounts have to be added to the dev portal for Facebook for anything to work. It should return an error if the user is not authorized.

Comment: I have implemented the `loginView(loginView:FBLoginView, error:NSError?)` function to check for errors and none have been returned. As I mention in the update above, I do wonder if this isn't a problem with iOS 8 Beta 4. My user is in the dev portal as the app Administrator. Plus, I am able to login fine on simulator, so I doubt it's a problem with my Facebook setup.

Comment: You shouldn't really rely on proper functionality for ... anything really with SDKs and the iOS Beta, many things have been braking and if you're using swift... that's even worse considering how rapid the language has been changing. At this point, you really shouldn't focus on this bug and just wait to see what happens with the next update. Just use it where ever it works and focus on that, but no matter what you're going to have to change your code in the next few Swift updates. They aren't done making bridging and optional adjustments (along a long list they have of things they are doing)